# Efficiently edit strings and convert to floats in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have a large dataset (appx 1GB, there is a column of salary ranges given in strings '20000-30000' for example. I want to remove everything after the hyphen and convert to a float. However this isn't always there, so I need to also have some conditional in there to check if it is there.

Is there a quick Pandas way to do this other than to iterate over the entire column converting each one individually? I feel like there must be as this seems like a common issue, however similar questions don't address the problem of large datasets.

Example inputs would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'salary': ['200 - 300', '400', '400-500', '600', '-']})

df
Out: 
      salary
0  200 - 300
1        400
2    400-500
3        600
4          -
```

for these values preferred outputs are:

```
   salary
0     200
1     400
2     400
3     600
4       0
```

The `0` can really be any filler value, I've just chosen `0`.

Comment: Could you show sample data of the column, showing the difference between strings having hyphen and the ones not having. And, expected output for both scenarios. Without seeing the data, I'm assuming `df['salary'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0]).astype(int)` should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `apply`

```
In [111]: df = pd.DataFrame({'salary': ['200 - 300', '400', '400-500', '600', '-']})

In [112]: df['salary'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0].strip()).replace('', '0').astype(int)
Out[112]:
0    200
1    400
2    400
3    600
4      0
Name: salary, dtype: int32
```

Another, using `regex` and string methods.

```
In [134]: df['salary'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).fillna(0)
Out[134]:
     0
0  200
1  400
2  400
3  600
4    0
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, though I've never encountered lambda before - how does this work? thanks!

Comment: @skailasa, `lambda` is one of two keywords used in Python to define a function, the other being `def`. You'll often see `lambda` used to create one-liner functions to pass into `apply`, `map`, and `reduce`. Here's one of the best writeups I've found on Python lambda functions, with examples and insightful comments at the bottom: https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Thanks, that article was really clear.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Salary=['200-400', '500', '600-700']))

df

    Salary
0  200-400
1      500
2  600-700
```

**`pandas`**
[**`pd.Series.str.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
df.Salary.str.split('-').str[0].astype(float)

0    200.0
1    500.0
2    600.0
Name: Salary, dtype: float64
```

**`numpy`**
[**`np.core.defchararray.split`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.split.html)

```
splits = np.core.defchararray.split(df.Salary.values.astype(str), '-')
df.assign(Salary=np.array([x[0] for x in splits], dtype=float))

   Salary
0   200.0
1   500.0
2   600.0
```